# Can we Test Real time Android Device using selenium webdriver?

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How do test real time Android mobile using selenium web driver?

Comment: Do you mean android mobile application?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the application, then unfortunately Selenium is not supposed to be used this way.

Consider reading
[Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/)

In case that you mean: testing the website in native Android and iOS browsers  then of cause it makes sense.

Hope this answers your question